# Android Show once Box

Tags: android

I have see in many Apps a "FirstStart" View with hints from the App.
Titanium Backup shows at the first start a View with the Rules of the App and after this the Changelog.

Is this "FirstStart" a Addon or how can i make this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not an addon. Just show a dialog using fragment manger and save a value to shared preferences.

```
Boolean isFirstRun = getActivity().getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREF, Context.MODE_PRIVATE).getBoolean("firstRun", true);
    if (isFirstRun) {
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getActivity().getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREF, 0);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor= sharedPreferences.edit();
        editor.putBoolean("firstRun", false);
        editor.apply();

        FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();

        MyDialogFragment dialog = new MyDialogFragment();
        dialog.show(fm, "myDialog");
    }
```

Comment: Thank you the answere is sometimes so near.